# Catch object from ajax - asp.net core 2.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to send whole object from javascript to asp.net core controller.

Here is C# class i am having:

```
public class AREvent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing it from ajax like this:

```
function Upp() {
    var ev = {};

    ev.ID = 1;
    ev.Title = "asd";
    ev.Text = "Some text";

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("e", ev);
    fd.append("aaa", "Some text");

    alert(ev.ID); // alerts 1

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Events/Add1",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fd,
        success: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

and here is controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Events/Add1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add1(AR.AREvent e, string aaa)
{
    /// aaa is passed as "some text"
    /// e is passed as null or as empty object
    object a = e;
    return Json("1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a FormData.
You have to pass the object like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Events/Add1",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(ev),
            contentType:  "application/json",
            success: function (result, text, xhr) {

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
            }
        });
```

And in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Events/Add1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add1([FromBody] AREvent e)
{
    AREvent a = e;
    return Json("1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to pass form data into the controller, there is no need to new a new js model named ev. You should directly add the property value in the form data model in the js and the asp.net core model binding will bind the value automatically. The model binding will map the property according to the form data name instead of a object.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
function Upp() {
  

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("ID", 1);
    fd.append("Title", "asd");
    fd.append("Text", "Some text");
    fd.append("aaa", "Some text2");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Events/Add1",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: fd,
        success: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Result:

[image]